# Gradle: using resources in a dependency jar as a sourceset

Tags: gradle, dependencies, source-sets

Suppose I have a `build.gradle` thus:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.group:some-app:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.group:some-app:1.0.1:sources'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        other {
             srcDir 'src/main/other'
        }
    }
}
```

So `some-app-1.0.1-sources.jar` has source files in it - not Java files, but files from which Java can be generated.

How do I include those files in `sourceSets` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the files from the source jar on the fly into a directory, and add the directory to a source set.

```
configurations {
   sourceJar
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.group:some-app:1.0.1'
    sourceJar 'com.group:some-app:1.0.1:sources'
}

def generatedDir = "$build/other"
task extractFiles(type: Copy) {

    from (zipTree(configurations.sourceJar.singleFile)) 

    into generatedDir 
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
             srcDir generatedDir
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm running into 2 errors with this. Possibly I'm just doing something wrong?
1) `InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':sourceJar' after it has been resolved.`  2) `Expected configuration ':sourceJar' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains 18 files.`

Comment: The source jar may have transitive dependencies. Try adding the "transitive=false". dependencies {
    sourceJar ('com.group:some-app:1.0.1:sources') { transitive=false 
}}

Comment: `transitive=false` hasn't fixed it. I can include all your code *except* the `from(zipTree(...))` line. That appears to be what breaks it. But is that referencing something earlier in the config?

Comment: Based upon what I've read elsewhere, I tried adding `doLast { ...}` to the task. It doesn't error, but I think it's also not running at all.

Comment: If I explicitly call the task with `gradle extractFiles`, I don't see anything extracted :(

Comment: `$build` does not exist, it should be `$buildDir`

Comment: can you show the dependencies of com.group:some-app:1.0.1:sources?

Comment: The transitive dependencies are many. I did add `{ transitive=false }`. And the non-source .jar is used as part of the normal build just fine.